# Keep the child process if the parent process was killed

Tags: vb.net, process

How do I keep my child process if my main or parent process was killed, killed in the task manager by "end process tree"?

```
    Private Sub Sexecute(ByVal exe As String)
        Dim getPath As String = Application.StartupPath
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        startInfo.FileName = exe
        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End Sub

     ''System.Threading.Timer
     Private Sub LockEpsonCallBack(ByVal state As Object)
        '''Check if Tree Locker is in the process
        Dim tlockerfound As Boolean
        For Each list As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("tlocker")
            tlockerfound = False
            If list.ProcessName = "tlocker" Then
                tlockerfound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If tlockerfound = False Then
            Sexecute("tlocker.exe")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Is there a possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I know you can set a thread to foreground (rather than background) which does the same thing. I'm not sure it there is an equivalent for process but you could see what happens using UseShellExecute or wrap it in a foreground thread.

Comment: I haven't use "UseShellExecute" but I doubt same thing happens, because using shellexecute in Delphi it also closes the child process when the parent process was killed, thanks for the comment.